# Is Quran the only true text of god?

Tags: quran, hadith

If the Quran is the true word of God and it has been protected by God while the Torah and Bible have not been protected by God and is not the word of God and is written by humans then, how are hadiths so different to the Torah and Bible; hadiths are written by humans and not protected by God so it should be neglected as we neglect the Bible and Torah, is that correct?

Comment: It is not "protection from God" that makes a text true. It is being authentic that makes it true. Obviously, Jews and Christians needed to follow the laws of their books even though they were not protected by God as long as they were authentic (or more authentic than not following them).

Comment: Thank you all for the comments